# Plot time series of credit ratings (letters) R ggplot2 stairs plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a stairs plot for a credit ratings time series, but the plot I obtain is disconnected in between each steps. I would like the plot not to have disconnections when the credit rating goes up or down. See example below.

```
ratings = c("BB+", "BBB+", "A-", "A", "A")
dates = c("2005-04-27", "2005-04-28", "2008-05-01", "2009-05-02", "2010-05-03")

df = data.frame(dates, ratings)

df$ratings = factor(df$ratings, levels=rev(unique(df$ratings))) # order credit ratings

library("ggplot2")
ggplot(df, aes(x=dates)) + 
  geom_step(aes(y = ratings))+
  ylab(label="Ratings") + 
  xlab("Date")
```

[image]

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(dates, ratings, group=1)) + geom_step()` but your current code does not produce that plot you've shown

Comment: What if I wanted to plot three series of ratings on the same plot? Say instead I would have df = date.frame(dates, ratings1, ratings2, ratings3) and I wanted to plot all three series on the same plot? I tried ggplot(df, aes(x=dates))+geom_step(aes(y=ratings1, group=1))+geom_step(aes(y=ratings2, group=1))+geom_step(aes(y=ratings3, group=1)) +
  ylab(label="Ratings") + 
  xlab("Date"), but the Y axis does not keep the right ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `geom_step` is built on `geom_line`, which defaults to splitting categorical factors into separate lines. So in this case, `geom_step` is working as intended, but because each category is on one horizontal line, you never see a step. We can overcome this by overriding the default grouping by setting `group = 1`. Also, when you create your example data, the date vector should be wrapped in `as.Date`.

```
ratings = c("BB+", "BBB+", "A-", "A", "A")
dates = as.Date(c("2005-04-27", "2005-04-28", "2008-05-01", "2009-05-02", "2010-05-03"))

df = data.frame(dates, ratings)

df$ratings = factor(df$ratings, levels=rev(unique(df$ratings))) # order credit ratings

library("ggplot2")
ggplot(df, aes(x=dates)) + 
  geom_step(aes(y = ratings, group = 1))+
  ylab(label="Ratings") + 
  xlab("Date")
```

[image]

### Plotting multiple time series

To plot multiple series as intended with ggplot, you want "long" data, in which each row contains a single observation. This means that rather than having a column for each series, you'll have a column for the ratings, a column for the corresponding dates, and a column that labels each series (the `dplyr` or `reshape2` packages are good at transforming data to long format). For example:

```
ratings = c("BB+", "BBB+", "A-", "A", "A", "BBB+")
dates = as.Date(c("2005-04-27", "2005-04-28", "2008-05-01", "2009-05-02", "2010-05-03", "2011-01-01"))
rating.series = factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))

df = data.frame(dates, ratings, rating.series)

df$ratings = factor(df$ratings, levels=rev(unique(df$ratings))) # order credit ratings

library("ggplot2")
ggplot(df, aes(x=dates)) + 
  geom_step(aes(y = ratings, group = rating.series, color = rating.series))+
  ylab(label="Ratings") + 
  xlab("Date")
```

[image]

Comment: May you have a look at the comment I posted above please?

Comment: This seems to work well, but the ordering does not work. With only one series, it was possible to order the Y axis with A as the highest value and BB+ as the lowest (see the plot in the question), how would you modify the code to achieve that?

Comment: Just try `y = factor(df$ratings, levels=(unique(df$ratings)))`

Comment: Is there anyway the colors could be changed to different types of lines to discern the series on the plot? For example, red becomes a full line and blue becomes a dashed line? This would be useful to print the plot in black and white.

Comment: The "lty" or "linetype" aesthetic does exactly that.